# How can i post photos to my Facebook page through .net console application?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get publish_pages and manage_pages permission for my Facebook app to post photos to my Facebook page via my console application?

Note: When i tried to send app review for manage_pages and publish_pages permission. i have entered required details and successfully uploaded screencasts video but unable to save it. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFdjF.png)
Help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

[Unable to submit app review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMZdr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide all the information needed. In your video, you need to show how your application request permission. Note that facebook updated their privacy policy. Please read their guidelines how to submit app to review.

> For your instance, in your video you need to show how your app request
>   permission on the facebook of the specific user. Note that all of your
>   request permission must need the user interaction.

Show that in your video and your review will be submitted.

And also note that when you make an app that uses facebook SDK or any related to facebook, you mustn't do it programmatically.

> Example: In publishing, you can't change the caption or the message
>   programmatically, the user will the one to type all of that.

Show that in your video and your app will be approved.